# Assertion failure in JSR223 Sampler

Tags: jmeter, assertion, jsr223

I want to do a Assertion failure in JSR223 Sampler based on the values i detected in 2 Post processors above. I tried importing AssertionResult in JSR223 Sampler but it is unable to invoke the method.

Getting the following error in log:

javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `SampleResult.setIgnore(); import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLog . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setFailure( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult : at Line: 24 : in file: inline evaluation of:`SampleResult.setIgnore(); import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLog . . . '' : AssertionResult .setFailure ( true )

Is this a right way to call this method?

---

JSR223 Sampler

```
SampleResult.setIgnore();
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction;
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

//Final Response Assertion
String s1 = "N";
String s2 = "N";

if( ${__isVarDefined(s_check)} == true )
{
s1 = vars.get("s_check");
}
if( ${__isVarDefined(s_check_1)} == true )
{
s2 = vars.get("s_check_1");
}

if( (s1 == "false" && s2 == "false") || (s1 == "false" && s2 == "N") || (s1 == "N" && s2 == "false") )
{
AssertionResult.setFailure(true); //NOT WORKING
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("accountID page is not loaded"); //NOT WORKING
ctx.setTestLogicalAction(TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD); //WORKING
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have `AsserionResult` shorthand in the JSR223 Sampler, either move your code to [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and change first line to `prev.setIgnore(true)` or change these lines:

   ```
   AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
   AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("accountID page is not loaded")
   ```

   to these ones:

   ```
   SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
   SampleResult.setResponseMessage("accountID page is not loaded")
   ```
2. Inlining [JMeter Functions or Variables in Groovy scripts is not recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), you should also change this lines:

   ```
   String s1 = "N";
   if( ${__isVarDefined(s_check)} == true )
   {
   s1 = vars.get("s_check");
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   s1 = vars.get('s_check') ?: 'N'
   ```

More information:

- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)
- [Groovy Elvis Operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. I will take care of it.